# How to share files from Mac mountain lion to windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, network-shares, file-sharing, smb

I've been trying to share one particular folder on my imac to other windows users but having difficulty of sharing just one particular folder. I've tried to google around and the methods work only for an entire mac sharing. I just want to share 1 folder but can't. Can anyone show me how to do it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences

Select Sharing

Turn on file sharing

This is what it should look like:
[image]

Under shared folders in the middle, You'll see the + Icon.  Click it and select the folder you want to share.  Then click the Options button on the right.  This window will come up:

[image]
Fill in the check box for Share Files and Folders using SMB (Windows).
You will now see it on the Windows machine (I tested it).